# database of German - English translations

Tags: android, offline, translate

I am dealing with a mobile application where it should perform a translation of words which works offline-(not online using any api -bing/google). how can I  perform any translation of words (like german--->english)in android. just like WORDLENS/any offline translator works.

are there any databases available to translate from german to english.

Comment: You want to translate only words, or entire sentences?

Comment: words would be good to translae....

Comment: @ raghav  : How can i translate the sentences

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be hard to find. There are paid versions: http://www.language-databases.com/database-english.html which will cost you quite a bit of money for a license. You could try to write a script that uses a german word list to get translations from various online sources. It might take you a couple of weeks, but it will be less expensive. (Not sure what the legal ramifications are.)